# Dockerfile - how to use ENVs inside a quoted RUN command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that contains a `sed` command. I want to dynamically change the values that are being replaced in `sed` using `ENV`s. However, I'm not really sure how to do this, or if it's even possible.

I've tried directly using the `ENV` key within the quotes like so:

```
RUN sed -i "s|urlVal: ${OLD_URL}|urlVal: ${NEW_URL}|" ./example.txt
```

but it reads the value literally. I was considering concatenating the `sed` string with the `ENV`s, but I wasn't sure how to do so, and I couldn't find anything in the docs about it.

Say that my Dockerfile looks like the following example:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV OLD_URL=example.com
ENV NEW_URL=www.test.com

COPY . .
RUN sed -i "s|urlVal: example.com|urlVal: www.test.com|" ./example.txt
```

**Is it possible to directly inject the `ENV` values into the `sed` command?**

Comment: or you can try `RUN sed -i "s|urlVal:$(echo $OLD_URL)|urlVal: $(echo $NEW_URL)|" ./example.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It expands for me, so I suspect the issue is in your file contents itself, or how you are running the container:

```
$ cat df.env5
FROM ubuntu
ENV OLD_URL=example.com
ENV NEW_URL=www.test.com

RUN echo "urlVal: example.com" >/example.txt
RUN sed -i "s|urlVal: ${OLD_URL}|urlVal: ${NEW_URL}|" /example.txt
CMD cat /example.txt

$ docker build -t test-env5 -f df.env5 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  30.72kB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 775349758637
Step 2/6 : ENV OLD_URL=example.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> edcd532bebba
Step 3/6 : ENV NEW_URL=www.test.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d71251cf653
Step 4/6 : RUN echo "urlVal: example.com" >/example.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0ff55a14765f
Step 5/6 : RUN sed -i "s|urlVal: ${OLD_URL}|urlVal: ${NEW_URL}|" /example.txt
 ---> Running in dabae6fb8f63
Removing intermediate container dabae6fb8f63
 ---> c7515a76e73e
Step 6/6 : CMD cat /example.txt
 ---> Running in 69739fd8de24
Removing intermediate container 69739fd8de24
 ---> ecbf606a343d
Successfully built ecbf606a343d
Successfully tagged test-env5:latest

$ docker run -it --rm test-env5
urlVal: www.test.com
```

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the documentation for [the PHP image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), and it seems they use the syntax I had above for modifying apache config files. I'm troubleshooting my Dockerfile now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the curly brackets, and use directly: `RUN sed -i "s|urlVal: $OLD_URL|urlVal: $NEW_URL|" ./example.txt`

You can imagine the statement being run on the cmd line.

```
export thisVar=thisVar_value
echo $thisVar
```

Output: `thisVar_value`

And using that logic, remove the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting and as @BMitch suggested, I found out that there is some issue with the Dockerfile. For some reason I'm able to attach a shell to the container and run the same command without any issues, but it doesn't do anything when building the image *(even when hard-coding the values)*.

Unfortunately I was unable to find the cause of the issue in my Dockerfile, so my current workaround is running the `sed` command in my `ENTRYPOINT` shell script using the `ENV`s I exported in the Dockerfile.